# fstream std::ios::binary printing in ASCII ? is it working correctly?

Tags: c++, fstream

i was trying to write some data to a file in binary, the following is the minimal reproducible example of the problem, i am trying to print two unsigned 64 bit integers to a binary file and read one of them again ... problem is that the data is not printed or read in binary.

```cpp
#inclue <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    uint64_t a = 1;
    uint64_t b = 2;
    uint64_t c;
    std::ofstream s("file.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    s << a << b;
    s.close();
    std::ifstream in("file.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    in >> c;
    in.close();
    std::cout << c << '\n';

    std::cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

the ouput of the above code is `12`, so i checked the file using notepad, and it had 12 written in it in ASCII, not in binary, i am using the latest version of msvc2017 on windows, i tried compiling it for x86 and x64, in debug and release mode and the error persists.

so is this its intended behavior ? and do i need to cast every variable to an array of characters when printing and reading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream input and output operators `>>` and `<<` are text-based. They will write the output as text, and read the input as text. Even for binary files.

To write raw binary data use the `write` function. And to read the raw binary data use `read`:

```
s.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&a), sizeof a);
s.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&b), sizeof b);

// ...

in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&c), sizeof c);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, and you're running Windows, you **might** see what `std::ios::binary` actually does. It tells the stream functions not to do text conversions. In particular, in text mode on Windows systems, `'\n'` gets written out as two bytes, `0x0D` followed by `0x0A` (or maybe the other way around), and on input that two-byte sequence gets translated into the single character `'\n'`. In binary mode there's only one character.

Stream inserters and extractors always traffic in text, not binary. To write and read values as binary you have to use the member functions named (oddly enough) `write` and `read`:

```
s.write((const char*)&a, sizeof(a));
s.write((const char*)&b, sizeof(b));

in.read((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
```

Comment: to be honest this is exactly the code people are trying to avoid when they use fstreams ... so it's disappointing that binary files still require the old C's read and write when working with them.

Comment: @AhmedAEK -- what would those people see as an alternative? Binary files inherently traffic in untyped data, so there's no reason for a more complexified interface. Of course, it's trivial to write your own wrapper: `template <class T> void write(std::ifstream& str, const T& val) { str.write((const char*)&val, sizeof(T)) }`. But ultimately that just masks the complexity of binary I/O, which is inerehently non-portable and, at best, tricky to get right.